# Custom action type can not be submitted after being published by a test user

Tags: submit, action, facebook-opengraph

The app I'm currently working on requires OpenGraph custom actions.
I have created and successfully published custom actions to my Test User.
However when I enter the Review Status page I am still unable to click Submit for the actions, I simply get a tooltip informing me that this action must be published.

Any and all help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a special test user by the name of Open Graph Test User is created and that's the one who needs to publish the actions.